# VBA on mac excel 2011

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to open a specific email within excel using VBA macro. The problem I've is that I'm not able to run Outlook.Application becouse there is no Outlook 14.0 library installed in my VBA References. I think it depends becouse I'm running into a MAC. The code where i get activex error is this:

```
Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Any idea to download from somewhere the MSOUTL.OLB mac version and make this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that Excel 2011 for OSX has not .NET support so it's not possible to load "Outlook.Application" library that is a Windows prerogative.

Comment: not sure it's a .NET issue. Do you even *have* Outlook.exe on your Mac?

Comment: .exe file are Windows OS's proprietary so they can't run under MAC OSX

Comment: OK, right. But you need an instance of Outlook (whatever file extension it is) on your computer in order to instantiate an `Outlook.Application` object. This should be doable on Mac, assuming there is an OSX compatible Outlook (there is such comatibility for Word.Application, etc.)